# KB2661254 breaks SharePoint

Tags: infrastructure, patching

Over the weekend, a variety of patches went out to our servers. One of those installed updates, [KB2661254](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2661254), broke our WSS 3.0 farm.

Specifically, we were seeing the following symptoms:

- Windows Server 2008 R2 machine w/ SSRS 2008 R2. Attempting to run a report directly on the SSRS server would display the IIS error page with a message "The resource cannot be found."
- Windows Server 2003 responsible for indexing/batch processing had only one webapp crash. Attempting to browse to the broken webapp would result in 401 UNAUTHORIZED errors.
- Windows Server 2003 (DEV.. actually running MOSS 2007) has a similar issue except all webapps seem to be broken. Attempting to browse to Central Admin gives 403 Forbidden. Attempting to browse to a random site collection gives 404. Curiously, I can still get output from an `stsadm -o enumsites`.

Seems that [others are experiencing the issue](http://onefootinthecloud.blogspot.com/2012/10/kb2661254-kills-my-sharepoint.html).

**Q: Can we keep the patch installed and fix SharePoint?**

The workaround is to completely uninstall the patch (warning, reboot may be required immediately). If you have the option, do **NOT** install this patch without first testing in DEV!

*Update*

Attempted to run psconfig and received the following errors (in Upgrade.log):

```
[SPIisWebSiteWssSequence] [ERROR] [10/23/2012 11:38:32 AM]: Action 3.0.3.0 of Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPIisWebSiteWssSequence failed.
[SPIisWebSiteWssSequence] [ERROR] [10/23/2012 11:38:32 AM]: InstallAspNet 174101101 failed.
[SPIisWebSiteWssSequence] [ERROR] [10/23/2012 11:38:32 AM]:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.EnsureAspNetScriptMapInstalled.Upgrade()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPActionSequence.Upgrade()
```

*Update 2*

I found [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/944267) searching for the error above. Looking at the "ASP.NET is registered incorrectly in the Internet Information Services (IIS) metabase" section. I was a little afraid of just running commands willy nilly so I checked the Application Configuration on one of my SharePoint Web Sites in IIS and noticed it no longer has the asp.net extentions (asmx, aspx, etc)!!

[image: Application Configuration]

Comment: Well.. I was assuming there might be a solution where we could keep the patch installed AND have SharePoint working.. but now that I think about it.. probably the only solution is to remove the patch entirely.

Comment: Have your tried re-running the Product Configuration Wizard to make sure everything is configured correctly?

Comment: @JohnChapman I tried running PSConfig and it failed (edited my question to include the error). Let me know if you need more info

Comment: I'm not certain if this works so snapshot everything - but if you delete the websites in IIS, are they not recreated upon running PSConfig?

Comment: Oh, FWIW, stsadm -o enumsites pulls out site collections that exist in the content databases, nothing to do with IIS.

Comment: @JamesLove I'm scared to delete the IIS site. Is there a good way to back this up first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kit! you should of had a disaster recovery plan in place before hand, not looking for one now! But that aside follow the steps of Migrating to a new server.

[Moving Sharepoint to New Server](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32549/moving-sharepoint-to-new-server)

Microsoft's official line on this patch is to uninstall and reinstall SharePoint, and always test patches out on a test server before applying to live.

After you have recovered spend some time looking into disaster recovery plans.

Comment: Totally agree.. Luckily, uninstalling the patch seemed to fix things. Plus, I'm on the dev side rather than infrastructure. :) How did you get the official line from Microsoft? Link?

Comment: The sys admin where I work put in a tech support ticket, they highly recommended the patch, but to do a re install after the update. (Rubbish if you ask me)