# Sizing of a SharePoint infrastructure

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infrastructure

I'm working for a customer that need all features of SharePoint 2013 enterprise and I have to estimate a correct sizing of the infrastructure. On this SharePoint, there will be almost 300 users with about 300 pages viewed/day.
The AD is already existing.
Could you help me on this task??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but good info nonetheless: http://sharepointintheprivatecloud.wordpress.com/2011/06/26/sharepoint-infrastructure-best-practices/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement seems pretty low to me (300 page views / day) but best practices would dictate a small farm to exist of 1 WFE server, 1 APP Server and 1 SQL Server, and a seperate AD which you already have, anyway. Use the [Hardware Requirements](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485%28v=office.15%29.aspx#hwLocServers) recommended by Microsoft to have an idea of individual server requirements. You need to read the document carefully, but to give you an idea:

- They consider <10.000 users a small deployment
- 4 cores minimum on all servers
- 8GB to 12GB RAM

Do keep in mind that each component places it's own requirements on the infrastructure, a big one being [Search](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219628%28v=office.15%29.aspx#HW_Enterprise) and another one being Office Web Apps (seperate server). [This is a good overview](http://blog.blksthl.com/2012/11/19/hardware-requirements-for-all-sharepoint-2013-components-summarized/), but keep in mind that the values may have been updated since then (I know they have on MSDN since SP 2013's release).

EDIT:

[In this slideshare](http://www.slideshare.net/jasonhimmelstein/sharepoint-performance-best-practices-from-the-field), it is mentioned that 500 **concurrent** users can bring a 4 server farm (4 cores, 16GB RAm each on average) to a crawl.

Comment: Thanks! One question, I already have my sharepoint installed on a single server, is it possible to change the infrastructure or do I have to rebuild my solution??? Thanks!

Comment: When you say *My* SharePoint, do you mean the production environment or your development machine ? The development machine can be just the one server, given it has enough RAM and CPU resources.

Comment: I have no development environment... only production (shame)

Comment: It is possible to transition to a farm setup, take a look at t his post for pointers: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32549/moving-sharepoint-to-new-server